# Flush Privileges in My SQL gives HY0000 Unknown Error

Tags: windows, mysql, permissions, sql

When I try to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` in MySQL I get this error:

`Error 1105 (HY000): Unknown error`

I am running the very latest version of MySQL 5.7 in Windows Server.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happened with me when I imported an older version dump, check mysql log files, I had to run `mysql_upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Google for `Error 1105 (HY000): Unknown error` gave me this as the first result. Also many other results.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,584361

```
If you get ERROR 1105 (HY000): Unknown Error after issuing a flush logs; make sure the permissions are set correctly on your log_error file. 

Hints 
* Find the path of log_error for mysql. Send the following to mysql: show global variables like '%err%'; 
* Check the permissions and make sure the UID (from ps -C mysqld -f at linux prompt) has permissions to write to the file 

Hoping this helps somebody. 

Adam
```

If the above doesn't work, look here because there are tons of hits: [Google Search Results](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Error%201105%20(HY000)%3A%20Unknown%20error&oq=Error%201105%20(HY000)%3A%20Unknown%20error&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

I hate to break it to you but if MySQL says unknown error, it means it's unknown and you're stuck figuring it out for yourself. You may need to report this as a bug if you are running the latest version of MySQL and still can't figure it out. There are numerous MySQL bugs filed due to users receiving this error.

Comment: I did do that -- and the search result you pasted is not relevant to this problem, and doesn't work.  I'm not flushing logs, I'm flushing Privileges.

Comment: @Abr Same error code.... doesn't matter what you're doing to cause it.

Comment: It does matter which command.  Also, the answer you gave above is for Linux and so doubly doesn't apply...

Comment: @Abr MySQL uses the same basic code for Windows and Linux so lots of things apply. I've updated my answer to be a bit more helpful/nicer.